# To save a .xml spreadsheet in a distinct folder of a Local Drive

Tags: excel, vba, filedialog

While pressing SAVE AS button a new dialogue box will open to key in the file name and the local drive to save it or preferably the spreadsheet should save directly in the specified folder of the local drive.
The code that I have written as stated underneath overwrite the file previously saved.

```
Sub SaveAsDialog()
  On Error Resume Next
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
     .Title = "Please choose a location and file name to save"
     .ButtonName = "SAVE AS"
     .InitialFileName = "E\Backup\SWARNALI\RTGS TEMPLATE(PARTY)\" & Range("").Value
     If .Show = 0 Then
       MsgBox "The file did not save.", vbCritical
       Exit Sub
     End If
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     .Execute
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  End With
End Sub
```

Sincerely requested to modify the code so that my purpose is satisfied.

Comment: Is `E\Backup` correct? I would expect it to say something like `E:\Backup` instead.

Comment: What do you expect `Range("").Value` to evaluate to?

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` then what error do you get on which line?

Comment: What about using [Application.Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.save) if you do want to save the file? There is no reason in using `FileDialog`